# TypeError: Object #<Receiver> has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to execute script on node, and get this error:
Maybe problem with socket.io version?
The code send the mouse coords to server and the server sends it to clients.
All help would be apreciated, thanks.

pi@webserver ~/cursores $ sudo node server.js

```
/home/pi/cursores/node_modules/websocket.io/lib/protocols/hybi-16.js:39
    .on('text', function (packet) {
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Receiver> has no method 'on'
    at new WebSocket (/home/pi/cursores/node_modules/websocket.io/lib/protocols/hybi-16.js:39:6)
    at Server.createClient (/home/pi/cursores/node_modules/websocket.io/lib/server.js:88:10)
    at Server.handleUpgrade (/home/pi/cursores/node_modules/websocket.io/lib/server.js:60:21)
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous> (/home/pi/cursores/node_modules/websocket.io/lib/websocket.io.js:92:8)
    at HTTPServer.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1990:14)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Script code:

```
var express = require('express');
var wsio = require('websocket.io');
var app = express.createServer();
var ws = wsio.attach(app);
app.use(express.static('public'));
ws.on('connection',function(socket) {
        console.log("Connection detected");
}); 
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope inside the handlers socket.on() is that available at runtime not scripting-time.
It could be that the function `broadcast` is not being seen inside the handler.
You might need to declare it before calling it.
You might need to force it to have a global scope.
See also
http://jondavidjohn.com/javascript-closure-explained-using-events/

Comment: I updated a simplified version of the code, throws the same error, no scope funciones here.